# Two identical answers

Tags: discussion, answers, policy

I just reviewed an answer from a new user [new user](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/42603/147) covering the same explanation as another already posted and more developed [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/42399/147). It is not the first time I come across this situation. Normally, it's because people posted almost at the same time. No need to bother since it's not done voluntarily in these cases.

Although I'm not calling it plagiarism because the answer is too short/simple for that, **do we need to have 2 identical answers**?

Is my definition of plagiarism too narrow?

Comment: Could you perhaps link the question here? Duplicate answers are generally not useful, but more importantly, very short (or link only) answers are not good answers and should be flagged down and edited/deleted.

Comment: It's hard to have a good discussion if we don't know what we're talking about. While I appreciate you want to keep the user anonymous, these discussions should be held on a case-by-case basis, so the community can take appropriate action with respect to the decision reached here.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, the answer posts are days apart.

In addition to the duplication of the content, the newer answer itself is very low quality and way too short. As such, I've flagged down the post as "low quality" - we can let the reviewers decide what to do after that.